# Vimeo API get request with empty result

Tags: php, get, vimeo-api

On the playground I get 100 results for `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`. In my app, running the same `GET` request, I get an empty result.

I'm authenticating using `Authorization: Bearer <PRIVATE ACCESS TOKEN>` in the header.

```
public static function headers($post = false)
{
    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: Bearer '.self::myToken(),
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    );
    if($post) $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    return $headers;
}
public static function get($url = '')
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, self::headers());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $error = curl_errno($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $error 
        ? array('status'=>'error','message'=>$error) 
        : array('status'=>'success','result'=>json_decode($result,true));
}
print_r(self::get('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos'));
```

If I don't include the auth token, I do get a result with an error about not having credentials. But when including the auth token, I get an empty response.

Again, in the API Playground, I get 100 videos in the result. What am I missing here? (The auth token is correct.)

All my videos are private, and the access token I'm using (the only one I've generated for my app) has full permissions, including private.

Comment: Can you echo out the entire url to see if it looks formatted correctly within the `get` function?  Obviously the API key is working .. What about the other parameters?

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. I just remembered my myToken function decrypts the token before returning it, and I forgot to encrypt my token before storing it.

Comment: In other words, the request is working fine now, now that I actually send it the correct token.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Did you make sure that your `myToken` function isn't decrypting your token before returning it? And if it is, are you storing your token encrypted in the first place?

A: No, I did not. No, I was not.

For posterity, the above is an example of a working API request, so long as you pass it the token correctly.